# Summarizing a pandas DataFrame by group using a custom function results in wrong output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a *pandas* DataFrame that I want to summarize by group, using a custom function that resolves to a boolean value.

Consider the following data. `df` describes 4 people, and for each person the fruits they like.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["danny", "danny", "danny", "monica", "monica", "monica", "fred", "fred", "sam", "sam"],
    "fruit": ["apricot", "apple", "orange", "apricot", "banana", "watermelon", "apple", "apricot", "apricot", "peach"]
})

print(df)
##      name       fruit
## 0   danny     apricot
## 1   danny       apple
## 2   danny      orange
## 3  monica     apricot
## 4  monica      banana
## 5  monica  watermelon
## 6    fred       apple
## 7    fred    apricot
## 8     sam    apricot
## 9     sam       peach
```

I want to summarize this table to find the people who like ***both*** `apricot` *and* `apple`. In other words, my *desired output* is the following table

```py
# desired output
##      name     fruit
## 0   danny     True
## 1  monica     False
## 2    fred     True
## 3     sam     False
```

*My attempt*

I first defined a function that searches for string(s) existence in a target list:

```py
def is_needle_in_haystack(needle, haystack):
  return all(x in haystack for x in needle)
```

Examples that `is_needle_in_haystack()` works:

```py
is_needle_in_haystack(["zebra", "lion"], ["whale", "lion", "dog"])
# False

is_needle_in_haystack(["rabbit", "cat"], ["hamster", "cat", "monkey", "rabbit"])
# True
```

Now I used `is_needle_in_haystack()` while grouping `df` by `name`:

```py
target_fruits = ["apricot", "apple"]

df.groupby(df["name"]).agg({"fruit": lambda x: is_needle_in_haystack(target_fruits, x)})
```

Then why do I get the following output, which clearly not as expected?

```py
##    fruit
## name         
## danny   False
## fred    False
## monica  False
## sam     False
```

What have I done wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `haystack` is a Series, when called in [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), change to:

```
def is_needle_in_haystack(needle, haystack):
    return all(x in set(haystack) for x in needle)


target_fruits = ["apricot", "apple"]
res = df.groupby(df["name"]).agg({"fruit": lambda x: is_needle_in_haystack(target_fruits, x)})
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
        fruit
name
danny    True
fred     True
monica  False
sam     False
```

The `in` operator for Series, returns `False`, for example:

```
"hamster" in pd.Series(["hamster", "cat", "monkey", "rabbit"])
# False
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use some set logic to accomplish the same task:

```
target_fruits = {"apricot", "apple"}
res = (df.groupby('name', as_index=False)#['fruit'] # Add if you have more columns.
         .agg(lambda x: target_fruits.issubset(x)))
# target_fruits.issubset(x) = Are all values from target_fruits present in the Series?
```

Output:

```
     name  fruit
0   danny   True
1    fred   True
2  monica  False
3     sam  False
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also make `target_fruits` a `Series` and use `Series.isin()`:

```
target_fruits = pd.Series(["apricot", "apple"])

dfr = df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: target_fruits.isin(x['fruit']).all()) \
        .reset_index().rename(columns={0:'fruit'})

print(dfr)
```

**Result**

```
     name  fruit
0   danny   True
1    fred   True
2  monica  False
3     sam  False
```